# Change the middle value of numbers to "xxxx"

Tags: mysql, database, replace, numbers, workbench

In a column there are numbers, for ex. 015162238465, and I want to delete 4 numbers in the middle and replace them with xxxx. so that means it should look like this: 0151xxxx8465.

How can I achive that?

Comment: What are you trying to do this with? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your table is called `foo`, your column is called `bar` and your column holds text (`char`, `varchar`, etc.., not `integer`):

```
UPDATE foo SET bar = INSERT(bar, (LENGTH(bar) - 4) / 2 + 1, 4, 'xxxx');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Using REPLACE and MID function

```
SELECT 
REPLACE('015162238465',MID('015162238465',LENGTH('015162238465')/2,4),'xxxx')
FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: This is a little risky. Consider, for instance, `111111111111` which will become `xxxxxxxxxxxx`. Any time the middle 4 digits appears anywhere else in the value it will fail.

Comment: @gwcoffey thanks for pointing out. yes i din think of that case.